# css is being applied in reverse hierarchy

Tags: css, asp.net

I am using asp.net and creating the following in code.

```
<div class="menu-box">
<p class="customer-name" style="margin-top:10px;">@Model.name</p>
<p class="customer-number">Customer ID: @Model.id</p>

@for (var m= 0;m< Model.items.Count; m++)
{
    var i = Model.items.ElementAt(m);
    if (!i.isSubItem)
    {
        <div class="menu-box-item @if(i.selected) {<text>selected</text>}">
            <a href="/@i.controller">@i.text</a>

            @while (m+1<Model.items.Count && Model.items.ElementAt(m+1).isSubItem)
            {
                m++;
                i = Model.items.ElementAt(m);
                <div >
                    <a class="menu-boxsubitem @if(i.selected) {<text>selected</text>}" href="/@i.controller">@i.text</a>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

    }
}
<div class="menu-box-item">
    <a href="/Login">Log Out</a>
</div>
```

But looks like the css classes from the parent DIV is overriding the css of the child. Here is a screenshots of the chrome developer console. The relevant bits are highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu-box .menu-box-item a  -> line 99

.menu-box .selected a -> line 119
```

It is an expected behavior that line 119 override line 99.

You can try adding a weight -

```
.menu-box div.selected a
```

If it still doesn't work, you can either reorder them, or use `!important`.

Comment: i updated the image. line 106 and line 125 are overwritting 138

Comment: Well, you either gotta rearrange the order or use !important.